# S3.YML - Accessing a variable? based on the current Env?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, yaml

I'm using paperclip which has a /config/s3.yml file with the following:

```
common: &common
    access_key_id: XXXXXXXXXX
    secret_access_key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

development:
    <<: *common
    bucket: myapp-local-dev

test:
    <<: *common
    bucket: myapp-123-test

production:
    <<: *common
    bucket: myappname-313-production
```

In my view I would like to dynamically be able to do something like this:

```
    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/myapp-local-dev/1/photos/15/1/thumb/Logo%20Design%20by%20kuda-1.jpeg" />
```

or

```
    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/myappname-313-production/1/photos/15/1/thumb/Logo%20Design%20by%20kuda-1.jpeg" />
```

Somehow, knowing the current environment and then getting the bucket name. Possible? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml")[Rails.env]["bucket"]`

Should do the trick if you just want to return the bucket name.

If you're using Paperclip with aws/s3 this should be handled automatically though.

So:

`<%= image_tag @my_obj.image.url %>`
should return the desired url regardless of the environment

Hope that helps?